# How to remove a SCNTransformConstraint from node

Tags: swift, transform, scenekit

Hey im simply trying to figure out how to remove a `SCNTransformConstraint` from its node

I can't find anything and Apple's Developer website doesn't help is it possible to remove a constraint so the now physics and other forces/Impulse/Gravity can act on the node as normal.

Instead of the node being stuck to the constraint in definite

```
let constraint = SCNTransformConstraint(inWorldSpace: true, withBlock: {
    node, matrix in
    let newPosition = User.transform
    return newPosition
})

Ball.constraints = [constraint]
```

// Error here

```
Ball.removeAllConstraints()
```

Comment: I don't have a specific answer but the next thing I would try, in a general debugging sense, is to try assigning a null array.

Comment: bpedit is correct, `Ball.constraints = nil`